# plot a dictionary of dictionary using networkx

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I have this dictionary which has two dictionaries inside it

```
tdict={'a1':{
    'aa1':{'aaa101':{'information'},'aaa201':{'information'}},
    'aa2':{'cca101':{'information'},'aca201':{'information'}},
    'ab1':{'aasdfaa101':{'information'},'aadaa201':{'information'}}
}
       ,'a2':{
           'ab1':{'aasdfaa101':{'information'},'aadaa201':{'information'}},
           'ab2':{'zz101':{'information'},'azz201':{'information'}},
           'ac2':{'aaa101':{'information'},'aaa201':{'information'}}
       }
       ,'a3':{
           'ac1':{'aaa101':{'information'},'aaa201':{'information'}},
           'ac2':{'aaa101':{'information'},'aaa201':{'information'}}

       }}
```

I would like to plot the network and see each node that is connected to I used the `from_dict_of_dicts` method from `networkx` and it works but it does not show the final dict which has for example `aaa201,aaa101` but only shows the keys for these two values

[image]

how I can include  the nodes `aaa201,zz101` in the same plot

Comment: So the nodes are only the final inner values ? not the oe we see on the graph ?

Comment: Are the edges only `[['aaa101', 'aaa201'], ['cca101', 'aca201'], ['aasdfaa101', 'aadaa201'], ['aasdfaa101', 'aadaa201'], ['zz101', 'azz201'], ['aaa101', 'aaa201'], ['aaa101', 'aaa201'], ['aaa101', 'aaa201']]
` ?

Comment: its like 3 tier graph `[aa1,aa2]` are the edges for the bigger node a1 and the `[aaa1,aaa2]` are the edges of `aa1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to traverse the dictionary and populate the graph with nodes and corresponding edges:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tdict = {'a1': {'aa1': {'aaa101': {'information'}, 'aaa201': {'information'}}, 'aa2': {'cca101': {'information'}, 'aca201': {'information'}}, 'ab1': {'aasdfaa101': {'information'}, 'aadaa201': {'information'}}}, 'a2': {'ab1': {'aasdfaa101': {'information'}, 'aadaa201': {'information'}}, 'ab2': {'zz101': {'information'}, 'azz201': {'information'}}, 'ac2': {'aaa101': {'information'}, 'aaa201': {'information'}}}, 'a3': {'ac1': {'aaa101': {'information'}, 'aaa201': {'information'}}, 'ac2': {'aaa101': {'information'}, 'aaa201': {'information'}}}}
G = nx.Graph()
def create_graph(d, g, p = None):
   for a, b in d.items():
      g.add_node(a)
      if p is not None:
         g.add_edge(p, a)
      if not isinstance(b, set):
         create_graph(b, g, a)

create_graph(tdict, G)
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]